# How to convert html table to PDF using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to generate one PDF file using Rails 3. I have a table with some values and i want to display these data in PDF. I have written some code which are explained below.

**index.html.erb:**

```
<h1>Choose the option</h1>
<p>
    <%= link_to "new input",products_new_path %>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Product name</th>
       <th>Product Catagory</th>
    </tr>
    <% @product.each do |p| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= p.p_name %></td>
        <td><%= p.p_catagory %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**products_controller.rb:**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @product=Product.all
        respond_to do |format|
           format.html
           format.pdf do
              pdf = Prawn::Document.new
              send_data pdf.render, filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
            end
        end
    end
    def new
        @product=Product.new
    end
    def create
        @product=Product.new(params[:product])
        if @product.save
            flash[:notice]="Data submitted"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "index"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not finish"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'prawn'
```

> config/initializer/mime_type.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and also let me to know how can i run app(e.g-localhost:3000/products.pdf) for getting this pdf file.

Comment: Fix formatting issues

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to add this line to your Gemfile to generate a table with prawn :

```
gem 'prawn-table'
```

Make sure you are using these version :

```
bundle show
  # * prawn (2.0.1)
  # * prawn-table (0.2.1)
```

In your controller, if you want to generate the PDF file when index action is called you can add this into it :

```
def index
  @products = Product.all

  require "prawn/table"
  require "prawn"

  Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") do |pdf|
    table_data = Array.new
    table_data << ["Product name", "Product category"]
    @products.each do |p|
      table_data << [p.name, p.category]
    end
    pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true })
  end
end
```

You can add some html syntax if you want to it :

```
["<b>#{p.name}</b>", "<i>#{p.category}</i>"]
```

Here is the result :
[image]

Comment: @ ZazOufUml : after adding your all code it is again throwing error -uninitialized constant Prawn::FLOAT_PRECISION.

Comment: @satya on which line ? Try just with product's name to begin

Comment: @ ZazOufUml :in this Prawn::Document.generate("test.pdf") do |pdf| line that type of error is showing.

Comment: @satya have you run `bundle install` with the new added gem and restarded your server? Please give the full error log, use http://pastebin.com/ if needed. I created a rails app from scratch with only this in my index and it worked great, there must be something else...

Comment: @ ZazOufUml : Yes, i have run bundle install but still this type of error is there.Check my full error log.NameError in ProductsController#index

uninitialized constant Prawn::FLOAT_PRECISION
Rails.root: C:/Site/generate

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:12:in `block in index'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:6:in `index'

Comment: @satya It looks like an incompatibility. Please make sure you use the good version of prawn. I updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77201/discussion-between-zazoufumi-and-satya).

Comment: @ ZazOufUml : i became able to clear that error by inserting the proper prawn and prawn-table gem but unable to produce the pdf file.Usually i am getting the html table in index page(i.e-localhost:3000).Can you please help me how to generate the pdf file.

Comment: @satya, how are you making that PDF either by clicking on link "Download PDF" or by url of index page (localhost:3000)?

Comment: @ Chitra : I want to click on a link "Download pdf" and download the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

@satya, I'll suggest you to use 'prawn' and 'prawn-table' gem.

Steps to create pdf is -

1: #create pdf object

```
  pdf = Prawn::Document.new()
```

2: #assign the value in pdf object

```
  pdf.text "To Date - #{extra_data[:to_date]}"
```

For more info you can watch this vedio -

http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn

Comment: @ Chitra :I have already used 'prawn' and 'prawn-table' gem.But got the error uninitialized constant Prawn::FLOAT_PRECISION.

Answer (score 0):

@satya, use this-                                                           - > return send_data Product.get_product_report_runtime_pdf(input_data), type: :pdf, filename: "Units_report_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}.pdf" will return the run time created pdf and if you want html page as well then dont use return before send data.

Under Product model -> here I am returning the blank pdf, so use the required code whatever you want in your pdf.

def  get_product_report_runtime_pdf

```
 pdf = Prawn::Document.new 
 return pdf.render
```

end